# Couldn't create image from OpenPLI repository in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am a newbie to PVR Set top boxes development. I would like to work on a UI customisation for a PVR set top box. So when i searched, i found out [Open PLI](https://openpli.org/). So i followed their basic tutorial which seemed very easy to accomplish from [here](https://wiki.openpli.org/Information_for_Developers). I have done all the steps without a hitch except the last one. When i first ran the last command `MACHINE=dm8000 make image` in terminal for doing the test build, first i got the error that `/usr/bin/env 'python3\r' is Not a file or directory`. Then i found out that it is the `CRLF` and `LF` line returning problem between Linux and Dos. Then i fixed it by converting the whole `bitbake` folder and its contents to unix formatted line endings using the `dos2unix` terminal tool. Then i noticed some jobs running, but again i hit the problem where the `Checksum` of the `licences` from the `openembedded` repository didn't match the downloaded one. So i went to the `openembedded` official repository and then replaced the local ones with the correct ones and that issue is fixed. Then now i started getting another problem that the tools from `openembedded-core/meta/recipes-xxxxxx` are failing. The log of the  current issue i am facing is as below

```
user@TLSPC-AND71:~/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core$ MACHINE=dm8000 make image
Building image for dm8000
Loading cache: 100% |######################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 3405 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |####################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:14
Parsing of 2880 .bb files complete (2588 cached, 292 parsed). 3692 targets, 655 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.34.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "ubuntu-18.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "mipsel-oe-linux"
MACHINE           = "dm8000"
DISTRO            = "openpli"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "homebuild"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "o32 fpu-hard mips32"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
meta-oe           
meta-filesystems  
meta-multimedia   
meta-networking   
meta-python       
meta-webserver    = "HEAD:dfbdd28d206a74bf264c2f7ee0f7b3e5af587796"
meta              = "HEAD:93dd2f9f3edf0584f9e806c629611d645dd72dbf"
meta-openpli      
meta-dream        = "develop:7614d888ee07baff7a3197f00051e0f6bac00782"
meta-vuplus       = "HEAD:4666f262c93c379678585b97d99375690d90e0fa"
meta-xsarius.pli5 = "HEAD:becd6945c9cc29a290b90c1bfa9d8b23c784d686"
meta-qviart       = "HEAD:e29333f48e443c02c171b148b28e214758f5c649"
meta-xp           = "HEAD:42958cf03e531dd9447b2f06fcba934cdf1d85b8"
meta-xtrend       = "HEAD:0bb2fec713b620d36c0734118edd3ec03e675b89"
meta-formuler     = "HEAD:b5cd4f24b62825740dc2d43b2ebd22b07b9ecd05"
meta-gfutures     = "HEAD:10c7ab9a58d738c634613163ebb8b82f4c842573"
meta-xpeedc       = "HEAD:f12908a5573de8a6a06ad9f75081846a590511c4"
meta-zgemma       = "HEAD:b2aaedc62ffbb949485db90d9b0517fd6a0529ad"
meta-edision      = "HEAD:563c99925e465dc601b2096b4c066e8661478cc7"
meta-miraclebox   = "HEAD:99117bcc87c3bcf1885b631af915834e4d31bb9a"
meta-spycat       = "HEAD:a19f11bbcdcad969e9f6f8d2c30df0653427d4cb"
meta-gi           = "HEAD:01fd1e8256f53d40371e65514e13a53ef53e400d"
meta-sab          = "HEAD:92262feb14e4005c8096150daac7313e9cb3d85a"
meta-gigablue     = "HEAD:80a5584686f87feee6260d05f1e3df65b2271c84"
meta-amiko        = "HEAD:b6416ddfc6130265e0b3054d144b96b59fdf7a03"
meta-axasuhd      = "HEAD:f454aabecfdfccf2ec338a30971b20fdd1d58130"
meta-maxytec      = "HEAD:c7cbbeefae15b3d6cdeb419f72f5595e978c83e4"
meta-octagon      = "HEAD:25af00715c91d1f17ca7db9b581060071a44cf9d"
meta-local        = "develop:7614d888ee07baff7a3197f00051e0f6bac00782"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:c6aa602d0640040b470ee81de39726276ddc0ea3"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:06
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: pkgconfig-native-0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+edf8e6f0ea-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/build/tmp
/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+edf8e6f0ea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch fix-glib-configure-libtool-usage.patch
patching file glib/configure.ac
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1438 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1503 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 1582 (different line endings).
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- rejects in file glib/configure.ac
Patch fix-glib-configure-libtool-usage.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: pkgconfig-native-0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+edf8e6f0ea-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+edf8e6f
0ea-r0/temp/log.do_patch.24110
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_patch) fa
iled with exit code '1'
ERROR: file-native-5.30-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/file-nativ
e/5.30-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch debian-742262.patch
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file magic/Magdir/commands
Hunk #1 FAILED at 57 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file magic/Magdir/commands
Patch debian-742262.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: file-native-5.30-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/file-native/5.30-r0/temp/log.do_patch.2435
7
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/file/file_5.30.bb:do_patch) failed with
 exit code '1'
WARNING: dbus-native-1.10.14-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/dbus/dbus-1.10.14.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 159 tasks of which 143 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
  virtual:native:/home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_patch
  virtual:native:/home/user/Documents/kautham/openpli40/openpli-oe-core/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/file/file_5.30.bb:do_patch
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There were 4 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'image' failed
make: *** [image] Error 1
```

I am not sure what is the problem. But when i looked at the tutorial and forum it was written with Ubuntu 12.02 and 14.04 in mind. But i am using 18.04. Can it be a problem?

My System Config:
Intel-i7, 256 GB SSD, 16 GB RAM, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I would expect you have another meta-layer in use with a bbappend that adds some patches to the original code.  Those are not longer in sync with the meta layer that holds the bb recipe.  Could you not leave most of your meta layers to a released version (e.g. Thus, Warrior, Zeus, ..) to prevent this?

Comment: @vermaete Thanks for your Comment, But i am a complete newbie to bitbake. So could you please tell me where and how to bbappend the meta- layer or where to set the meta-layer to release version.

Comment: Although it's probably safer to keep all meta-layers in the same version, Ross will have to correct answer.  The CRLF/LF fixed probably corrupted the patch files.

Comment: As @vermaete mentioned i am getting errors from the patch files. I tried to convert only the folder where the licences are stored in the openembedded repository and then i got a few checksum errors i previously got was removed. but then the patch errors came again.

Comment: @vermaete Thanks for your solution of git config change. It worked and i am able to build the source without any errors. Could you please post that comment as an answer. I will select your answer as solution.

Comment: The honor goes to Ross Burton :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire problem is due to the CRLF vs LF issue that you fixed for bitbake itself.  Run that tool over *all* of the layers you checked out, or ideally figure out why the line endings are Windows-style and fix that: maybe you did the initial clone in Windows before moving to Linux?  If so, just re-clone in Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to run the `dos2unix` tool all over the project folder. Also the project is cloned in Ubuntu machine. It wasn't copied or migrated over from a windows machine. Straight from git-hub clone.

Comment: I tried as you said but the patches from the tools in the `openembedded` repository are getting broken. But the previous Checksum errors i got were cleared.

Comment: check: https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings to configure the line endings in git.  A checkout of all layers without any modification (eg dos2unix) probably what you need.

Comment: Yes Configuring the Line Endings in git solved the problem